# A Maximising Puzzle Gift for my Girlfriend and I's 28th month Anniversary

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

The 28th of december 2018 will exactly be the 28th month since I date my fabulous girlfriend, by this time she'll be 18 years old. Here's a puzzle I'll give her this day :

### Classical part

> Maximize $\ \ \ \ 2\ \ \ \ 8\ \ \ \ 1\ \ \ \ 2\ \ \ \ 2018 + a\times18$

with two constraints :

- You have to insert exactly $12-a$ symbols within

> $+,\times,/$ and $-$

- The final result must contains the digits 2 and 8 at least one time. (so 2328 is a possible maximized value, 2323 isn't)

Maximize means you have to find the greatest number. "$($" and "$)$" (braces // embrace) are allowed in an infinite number of time.

Concatenate numbers is not allowed.

### Magical part

If you guys are just too strong for the classical part, there is a Magical part where you have to insert exactly $12-a$ symbols within :

> $+,\times,/,-,!, |n|$ (absolute value of the integer $n$, counted as 1 symbol) and $!!$(double factorial)

Comment: May we use "()" or "|x|", for the equation?"

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Oh yes, good remark, as "(" and ")" are braces (parallelization with embrace), you can use them in an infinite number of time :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I added the absolute value in the magical symbols :P

Comment: What if your girlfriend is on-site and looks up the answer here before you ask her?

Comment: @WaisKamal I know she won't because we are French and she rarely visits English websites ^^

Comment: Is implicit multiplication allowed?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yes it is !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the maximum is

> 1,312,848

By

> $2*(8+1)*2*(2018+8)*18$

I only could make 4 numbers higher and none of them have both a 2 and an 8. Here they are.

> $2*8*(1+2)*(2018+8)*18 = 1750464$
>  $2*8*((1+2)*2018+8)*18 = 1745856$
>  $2*(8*(1+2)*2018+8)*18 = 1743840$
>  $(2*8*(1+2)*2018+8)*18 = 1743696$

Answer (score 3):

## Classical part

My result is:

> (2 + 8 + 1 - 2) * (2018+8)*18 = 328212

Since the first constraint:

> 4 operands so a = (12 - 4) = 8

And the second constraint:

> final result has two '2' and an '8'

## Magical Part

My result is (approximated):

> (2 * 8! * 1 * 2) !* (2018 + 6) * 18 = 1.3669210815446285 × 10^769843

Since the first constraint:

> 6 operands so a = (12 - 6) = 6

And the second constraint:

> final result has several '2' and '8' (as shown in the most significant ciphers we have two '2' and two '8')

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.se! That's a very well written and formatted answer! Hope to see you around in the future. In the meantime feel free to take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), browse the [Questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions), and make yourself comfortable here!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.stackexchange ! This is a nice answer and currently the greatest one for Classical part :D

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I’m getting this wrong, but I know

> $28122018+12 \times 18=28122342$ might work, for $a=12$. It’s also possibly possible to do $28122018!!^{(12-a)} + (a \times 18)$ which ought to be huge numbers too..

Comment: You were not supposed to concatenate numbers, it's true I should have specify it in my puzzle (it's done now) ^^ However, I +1 you because it's a nice answer if concatenate is allowed :)

Comment: For the magical part, it is not possible to add a number $(12-a)$ neither to exponent it

Answer (score 2):

A possible result for the classical part, might be against the rules, though:

> $2\color{red}\times8\color{red}{{}\times{}(}1\color{red}+2\color{red}{){}\times{}}2018\color{red}{{}\times{}(}{+7}\color{red}{){}\times{}}18=1\color{blue}{2\,2}04\,\color{blue}864$
>  Adds $12-7=5$ operations and $2$ sets of braces, and uses a unary plus. However, I am unsure if adding operations (and not just braces) inside the $2018+7\times18$ is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A maximized possible value for the classical part that I hope you will beat :

> $8218$

Because :

> $2+8\times(1/2)\times2018+8\times18 =8218$

First constraint :

> $a = 8$, $12-a=4$ symbols that are $+$, 2 $\times$ and one $/$

Second constraint :

> 1 two and 2 eights

Comment: Shouldn't switching the second operation into its opposite yield a larger number? That number also fits the constraints with 2 and 8. Alternatively, the third into its opposite.

Comment: @nishuba unless I didn't understand your propositions, I get two numbers that don't contain any 8 with your operations. You suggested to transform the division by a multiplication, right ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I thought I could multiply the whole result by 4 in that way...

Answer (score 0):

My answer is **INCORRECT I HAD A RANDOM FACTOR OF 2 IN MY CALCULATOR**:

> 3,487,248

Made by:

> ((2*8*(1+2)*2018)+8)*18

Which makes a:

> Equal to 8, as I added 4 symbols; **+*

And the result has:

> two 8s and one 2.

Comment: Wow, shame you had this factor of two because it'd be a really large answer !!

Comment: Yeah I typed it all out and then i put it in my calculator again to add a factorial to the end (replacing the 8 with 7 for the additional symbol) to work out the magical one but then realised :(

Comment: That's not cool, but I have a solution for your answer, even if it's not as good as you firstly found : you could replace your second * by a / ;)